# Significance of return false statement inside addEventListener function definition

Tags: javascript

I was going through following JavaScript code Snippet and I am unable to figure out the significance of **return false** statement in fire() function.

```
 var x=document.getElementById("OK_BUT");
 x.addEventListener("click", fire, false);
```

Definition of Fire Function

```
 function fire(e)
 {
                  ....................
                  .....................
     return false;/*=> What is the significance of this Statement??*/
 }
```

I think its due to browser compatibility. Would be great if somebody explains its significance!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the same as e.preventDefault();

More info can be found in this thread:
[event.preventDefault() vs. return false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357118/event-preventdefault-vs-return-false)

Answer (score 1):

This would possibly be added to prevent the default behavior happening on the form submission of the click event, i.e. ensuring the page doesn't post back once the event has been fired. `e.preventDefault()` would accomplish the same desired behavior.